# How to find number of characters matches in two strings?

Tags: python

How can I do this in Python?

```
first string = GOOD MORNING
second string = GOOD BYE
```

After 5 characters there is no match

in C, it can be done as:

```
length = strspn(str1,str2);
```

Comment: Your example and the reference function are entirely different. Which one of them are you expecting and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to find upto what position the two strings are equal.

Comment: Are you just going to keep asking "how do I replicate this C standard library function in Python"? Are you trying to port something to Python without knowing Python? You should probably try to figure this stuff out yourself; it's not that hard, and you'll learn something.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of diversity

```
from itertools import takewhile, izip
sum(1 for x in takewhile(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], 
   izip(iter('GOOD MORNING'), iter('GOOD BYE'))))
5
```

Comment: It works also with just``izip(first, second)``

Comment: @eyquem, indeed it does. The `iter` is in place to demonstrate that this works with iterators and not just sequences

Comment: In general, I don't like to import additional tools. But, as it is a stupid opinion, I upvote because I thought to ``sum()`` but didn't think to ``takewhile``

Answer (score 1):

```
def matcher(A, B):
    for i in range(min(len(A), len(B))):
        if A[i] != B[i]:
            return i
    return min(len(A), len(B))

print str(matcher("GOOD MORNING", "GOOD BYE")) + " characters match"

def strspn(A, B):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] not in B:
            return i
    return len(A)

print "129th has " + str(strspn("129th", "0123456789")) + " digits"
```

**Output**

```
5 characters match
129th has 3 digits
```

Answer (score 1):

Two methods:

```
first = 'GOOD MORNING'
second = 'GOOD BYE'

import difflib
sq = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,first,second)
m = min(len(first),len(second))
print sq.find_longest_match(0,m,0,m)[2]

print '-----------'

print (i for i in xrange(min(len(first),len(second)))
       if first[i]!=second[i]).next()
```

result

```
5
-----------
5
```

Comment: +1. `sq.find_longest_match(0,m,0,m)[2]` can be made more readable with `sq.find_longest_match(0,m,0,m).size`

Comment: @1_CR Fine remark. I wrote indexing ``[2]`` because I read in the doc : _"difflib.get_close_matches(]) Return a list..."_ and when I printed ``sq.find_longest_match(0,m,0,m)`` and obtained ``Match(a=0, b=0, size=5)``, I didn't realize that it isn't a real list but an instance of ``difflib.Match`` with attributes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
def strspn(s1, s2):
    m = min(len(s1), len(s1))
    mismatches = (i for i, (c1, c2)
                  in enumerate(zip(s1[:m], s2[:m])) if c1 != c2)
    return next(mismatches, m)
```

Comment: Do you know about the `next` function?  You could write `next((i for i, (c1, c2) in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)) if c1 != c2), m)`.

Comment: @DSM I did not know that function, love learning new built-ins, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> a = "GOOD MORNING"
>>> b = "GOOD BYE"
>>> temp = max(a, b)
>>> for x, y in enumerate(min(a, b)):
...     if temp[x] != y:
...             print x
...             break
... 
5
```

Comment: I asked @Hardy to take a look at the enumerate part of your solution but now that I look at it closely, I don't like the fact that you're recomputing `max(a, b)` in each iteration of the loop!

Comment: @1_CR Hmm, I might as well put it outside of the loop :p

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if python has a build-in function for that, but you can simply write yours

```
first = 'GOOD MORNING'
second = 'GOOD BYE'
len1 = len(first)
len2 = len(second)
count = 0
for i in range(len1):
    if i < len2 and first[i] == second[i]:
        count += 1
        continue
    else:
        break
return count
```

Comment: `len(first)` works with Python, not `first.length()`. Additionally, you may want to look at Haidro's enumerate solution

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "good morning"
b = "good bye"


differ_idx = None
for idx, a_b in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    a, b = a_b
    if a != b:
        differ_idx = idx
        break

print "first string = %r" % a
print "second string = %r" % b
if differ_idx is None:
    print "Strings match"
else:
    print "After %d characters there is no match" % differ_idx
```